# Lorentz invariance and Dirac Slash Notation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I have the following factor inside a scattering amplitude
$$\Big[\bar{u}(p')\not{l}\gamma^{\mu}\not{l}u(p)\Big] \ \Big[\bar{u}(q')\gamma_{\mu}u(q)\Big]$$
where $p$ and $p'$ are the initial and final momenta of an electron (let's say) and $q$ and $q'$ are the initial and final momenta of a hevy muon (for instance). The momentum label $l$ is used for a virtual particle. So, the above expression is to be part in a quantity (which is not symmetric nor antisymmetric in $l$ and) that is going to be integrated with respect to $l$.

Are there some symmetry arguments that reduce the expression above to something of the form
$$l^2\Big[\bar{u}(p')\gamma^{\mu}u(p)\Big] \ \Big[\bar{u}(q')\gamma_{\mu}u(q)\Big]$$
(without any residual terms)? If there is some trick, or some argument based on symmetry, I would like to know about it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**P.S.#1:** I know about the identiy $\not{l}\gamma^{\mu}\not{l}=2l^{\mu}\not{l}-l^2\gamma^{\mu}$, but it does not seem to be very helpful, as I would like to see whether or not the original expression reduces to a single term proportional to $l^2$ (unless there is another argument that reduces further the first term to something proportional to $l^2$).

**P.S.#2:** Feel free to consider the high energy limit, in which the electron (let's say) is considered to be approximately massless.

**EDIT:**
I have managed to bring the expression I am struggling with (or at least a part of it), to the following form
$$\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}
\frac{1}{(l^2-i\epsilon)(l^2-2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2-2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\\
\bar{u}(\textbf{p}')
\Big\{
-2i(2p'-l)^{\alpha} \gamma^{\mu}S_{\alpha\gamma}l^{\gamma}
-2i(2p-l)_{\alpha} S^{\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\mu}l_{\beta}
-4S^{\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\mu}S_{\alpha\gamma}l_{\beta}l^{\gamma}
\Big\}
u(\textbf{p})$$

Is there some argument for either of the first, second or the third term to vanish in the massive or even in the massless case (in which $S^{0i}=0$ and $S^{ij}\sim\epsilon^{ijk}p_k$ ?)

**My attempt for the last term:**
$$-4\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}
\frac{l_{\beta}l^{\gamma}}{(l^2-i\epsilon)(l^2-2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2-2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\bar{u}(\textbf{p}')
S^{\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\mu}S_{\alpha\gamma}
u(\textbf{p})
=\\
-2\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}
\frac{l_{\beta}l^{\gamma}}{(l^2-i\epsilon)(l^2-2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2-2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\bar{u}(\textbf{p}')
S^{\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\mu}S_{\alpha\gamma}
u(\textbf{p})
\\
-2\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}
\frac{l_{\beta}l^{\gamma}}{(l^2-i\epsilon)(l^2+2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2+2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\bar{u}(\textbf{p}')
S^{\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\mu}S_{\alpha\gamma}
u(\textbf{p})$$
where I have separated the integral into two, with the second being subject to the substitution $l\rightarrow-l$, and then
$$-2\!\int\!\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\!
\frac{l_{\beta}l^{\gamma}}{(l^2-i\epsilon)}
\Big\{\!
\frac{1}{(l^2-2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2-2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\!+\!\frac{1}{(l^2+2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2+2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\!\Big\}\\
\bar{u}(\textbf{p}')
S^{\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\mu}S_{\alpha\gamma}
u(\textbf{p})$$
Now, I can claim that $l_{\beta}l^{\gamma}=\eta_{\beta\delta}l^{\delta}l^{\gamma}=
\frac{1}{4}\eta_{\beta\delta}\eta^{\delta\gamma}l^2$ on the grounds of symmetry and hence
$$-\frac{1}{2}\!\!\int\!\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\!
\frac{\eta_{\beta\delta}\eta^{\delta\gamma}l^2}
{(l^2-i\epsilon)}
\Big\{\!
\frac{1}{(l^2-2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2-2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\!+\!\frac{1}{(l^2+2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2+2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\!\Big\}\\
\bar{u}(\textbf{p}')
S^{\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\mu}S_{\alpha\gamma}
u(\textbf{p})$$
which finally yields
$$-\frac{1}{2}\!\!\int\!\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\!
\frac{l^2}
{(l^2-i\epsilon)}
\Big\{\!
\frac{1}{(l^2-2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2-2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\!+\!\frac{1}{(l^2+2p'\cdot l-i\epsilon)(l^2+2p\cdot l-i\epsilon)}
\!\Big\}\\
\bar{u}(\textbf{p}')
S^{\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\mu}S_{\alpha\beta}
u(\textbf{p})$$
I am allowed to do that, right? So, if I am not mistaken anywhere, this last term does not vanish in the massless case, nor in the massive one. It is merely proportional to $p^xp^{'x}+p^yp^{'y}+p^zp^{'z}$, which does not vanish.

If anyone disagrees about the derivation of the last term or has any comments on the above, please let me know...

Comment: hint: in an integral over $d^4\ell$ you can replace $\ell^\mu \ell^\nu$ by $g^{\mu\nu}\ell^2$. Find out why.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment! You are referring to something discussed in page 191 (Eqs 6.45 & 6.46) in Peskin's and Schroeder's book. The authors employ a similar trick in computing integrals that are proportional to $l^{\mu}$ or $l^{\mu}l^{\nu}$. I understand this bit, but doesn't this trick imply that the remaining integrand must be symmetrical in $l$?